# How I can take mean for different subsets of a specific column in a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Given a sample data frame:

`dt <- data.table(value=1:10,start=c(1,4,5,8,6,3,2,1,9,4),finish=c(3,7,8,9,10,10,4,10,10,8))`

I want to add a new column which may be named as mean_column. i'th row of this colum should have the value

`mean( value[  seq( from = start[i], to=finish[i] ) ] )`

The real data I'm working on has 20 million row, so I need to find a fast way to do this calculation.

Edit: the value column in the data.table doesn't need to be an ordered sequence as in the example. Each value in this column may take any positive number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses non-equi joins from [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

```
dt <- data.table(value=c(10,1:9),start=c(1,4,5,8,6,3,2,1,9,4),finish=c(3,7,8,9,10,10,4,10,10,8))
dt[, id := .I]

dt[dt,
   on = .(id >= start,
          id <= finish),
   .(i.id, i.value, mean_col = mean(x.value)),
   by = .EACHI,
   allow.cartesian = T]

       id    id  i.id i.value mean_col
    <int> <int> <int>   <num>    <num>
 1:     1     3     1      10 4.333333
 2:     4     7     2       1 4.500000
 3:     5     8     3       2 5.500000
 4:     8     9     4       3 7.500000
 5:     6    10     5       4 7.000000
 6:     3    10     6       5 5.500000
 7:     2     4     7       6 2.000000
 8:     1    10     8       7 5.500000
 9:     9    10     9       8 8.500000
10:     4     8    10       9 5.000000
```

Trying on 2,000,000 rows this takes 4 seconds on my computer and provides same answer as @jay.sf.

```
n = 2e6
dt <- data.table(value = sample(1000L, n, TRUE), start = sample(n, n, TRUE))
dt[, finish := start + sample(30, n, TRUE)]
dt[finish > n, finish := n]

system.time({
dt[, id := .I]
  dt[dt,
     on = .(id >= start,
            id <= finish),
     .(i.id, i.value, mean_col = mean(x.value)),
     by = .EACHI,
     allow.cartesian = T]
})

##    user  system elapsed 
##   3.78    0.01    3.69 

#jay.sf base approach
system.time({
  FUNV3 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) x:y)
dt$mean.column2 <- with(dt, sapply(FUNV3(start, finish), function(x) mean(value[x])))
})

##   user  system elapsed 
##  24.45    0.04   24.72 

all.equal(dt$mean.column2,   dt[dt,
                                on = .(id >= start,
                                       id <= finish),
                                .(i.id, i.value, mean_col = mean(x.value)),
                                by = .EACHI,
                                allow.cartesian = T]$mean_col)

##[1] TRUE
```

Comment: When I change first value of the value,  column this ode gives inconsistent results. Forexample, let ```dt <- data.table(value=c(10,1:9),start=c(1,4,5,8,6,3,2,1,9,4),finish=c(3,7,8,9,10,10,4,10,10,8))```

Comment: Did you see the edit? I made the same mistake others made at first but now it should be correct.

Comment: Would you like to add between to the list of solutions?

Comment: @chinsoon12 I do not follow how to add ```between``` to this, mainly because I feel like I would need to use between in a loop to do it for each row.

Comment: @Cole Your answer is the fastest working answer until now.

Comment: @Cole I hope you don't mind I've included your solution in my [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859200/6574038).

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `apply` approach. Should take around 20 seconds for 1e6 rows.

```
dt$mean.column <- apply(dt[2:3], 1, function(x) 
  mean(dt$value[seq(x[1], x[2])]))
#    value start finish mean.column
# 1      1     1      3         2.0
# 2      2     4      7         5.5
# 3      3     5      8         6.5
# 4      4     8      9         8.5
# 5      5     6     10         8.0
# 6      6     3     10         6.5
# 7      7     2      4         3.0
# 8      8     1     10         5.5
# 9      9     9     10         9.5
# 10    10     4      8         6.0
```

It's around **30% faster, though**, if we **`Vectorize`** the `seq` function like this:

```
FUNV <- Vectorize(function(x, y) seq(x, y))
dt$mean.column2 <- with(dt, sapply(FUNV(start, finish), function(x) mean(value[x])))

stopifnot(all.equal(dt$mean.column, dt$mean.column2))
```

***Edit:*** `FUNV()` could actually be **improved** using something faster than `seq()` like `seq.int` or `:`.

```
FUNV2 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) seq.int(x, y))
FUNV3 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) x:y)
```

And here comes the **microbenchmark**:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply=apply(df.L[2:3], 1, function(x) mean(df.L$value[seq(x[1], x[2])])),
  FUNV=with(df.L, sapply(FUNV(start, finish), function(x) mean(value[x]))),
  FUNV2=with(df.L, sapply(FUNV2(start, finish), function(x) mean(value[x]))),
  FUNV3=with(df.L, sapply(FUNV3(start, finish), function(x) mean(value[x]))),
  data.table={      ## see Cole's answer
    dt.L[, id := .I]
    dt.L[dt.L, on=.(id >= start, id <= finish), .(i.id, i.value, mean_col=mean(x.value)),
       by=.EACHI, allow.cartesian=T]},
  times=3L)
# Unit: seconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld  
#      apply 26.736665 26.740363 28.701785 26.744062 29.68435 32.624629     3   c
#       FUNV 24.983665 26.513645 28.007959 28.043625 29.52011 30.996587     3   c
#      FUNV2 15.371551 16.031383 16.848238 16.691215 17.58658 18.481949     3  b 
#      FUNV3 14.156043 14.266123 14.436663 14.376203 14.57697 14.777744     3  b 
# data.table  2.138956  2.323735  2.426432  2.508515  2.57017  2.631825     3 a
```

Tested on:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(value=c(10, 1:9), start=c(1, 4, 5, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1, 9, 4), 
                 finish=c(3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 4, 10, 10, 8))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
set.seed(42)
df.L <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), 1e6, replace=TRUE), ]
dt.L <- dt[sample(1:nrow(dt), 1e6, replace=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Why not just `dt$mean.column <- apply(dt[,2:3], 1, mean)`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, value column doesn't need to be ordered sequence as in the example.

Comment: This takes 5 min in my computer.

Comment: @serdaryurek Try `FUNV3` which uses `:`, see edit, or _Cole_'s `data.table` approach seems to be fast.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach for this specific task of finding the mean. The values of "mean_column" can be computed as `(running_sum[finish[i]] - running_sum[start[i] - 1]) / (finish[i] - start[i] + 1)`:

```
cs = cumsum(dt$value)   # cumulative sum
s = dt$start - 1        # starting indices - 1
f = dt$finish           # ending indices

# curent sums at all starting indices
cs.s = s
i = which(s > 0)
cs.s[i] = cs[s]

# current sums at all ending indices
cs.f = cs[f]

# subtract and divide
(cs.f - cs.s) / (f - s)
#[1] 2.0 5.5 6.5 8.5 8.0 6.5 3.0 5.5 9.5 6.0
```

---

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e5L
dt <- data.table(id=1L:nr, value=1L:nr, start=sample(nr, nr, TRUE), finish=sample(nr, nr, TRUE))
dt[, c("start", "finish") := .(pmin(start, finish), pmax(start, finish))]

library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
NumericVector rngmean(IntegerVector start, IntegerVector finish, NumericVector value) {
    int sz = value.size();
    int i, j;
    double sum = 0.0;
    NumericVector csum(sz);
    NumericVector res(sz);

    csum[0] = value[0];
    for (i=1; i<sz; i++) {
        csum[i] = value[i] + csum[i-1];
    }

    for (i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        if (start[i]==1) {
            res[i] = csum[finish[i] - 1];
        } else {
            res[i] = (csum[finish[i] - 1] - csum[start[i] - 2]) / (finish[i] - start[i] + 1);
        }
    }

    return(res);
}
")

mtd0 <- function() {
    dt[dt, on=.(id>=start, id<=finish), allow.cartesian=TRUE, by=.EACHI, mean(x.value)]$V1
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    dt[, {
        cs <- cumsum(as.numeric(value))
        (cs[finish] - cs[start] + value[start]) / (finish - start + 1)
    }]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    dt[, rngmean(start, finish, value)]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L, mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2())
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval
 mtd0() 17431.150342 17431.150342 17431.150342 17431.150342 17431.150342 17431.150342     1
 mtd1()     4.520483     4.520483     4.520483     4.520483     4.520483     4.520483     1
 mtd2()     2.466647     2.466647     2.466647     2.466647     2.466647     2.466647     1
```

And when nr = 20e6,

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L, mtd1(), mtd2())
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 mtd1() 1402.2282 1402.2282 1402.2282 1402.2282 1402.2282 1402.2282     1
 mtd2()  711.9264  711.9264  711.9264  711.9264  711.9264  711.9264     1
```

Comment: @chinsoon12 : Thanks for taking the time to add benchmarks and improving the code

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

You can define your custom function `f`, and then use `apply()`

```
f <- function(v,s,d) mean(v[s:d])
val_vector <- dt$value
dt$mean <- apply(dt, 1, function(v) f(val_vector,v["start"],v["finish"]))
```

such that

```
> dt
   value start finish mean
1      1     1      3  2.0
2      2     4      7  5.5
3      3     5      8  6.5
4      4     8      9  8.5
5      5     6     10  8.0
6      6     3     10  6.5
7      7     2      4  3.0
8      8     1     10  5.5
9      9     9     10  9.5
10    10     4      8  6.0
```

Comment: An easy way to get slightly more performance is to extract value before hand. i.e.: ```val_vector = dt[["value"]]``` and passing that vector to the function.

Comment: @Cole yes, that improves the performance, but maybe OP wants more

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
dt <- data.table(value=1:10, 
             start = c(1,4,5,8,6,3,2,1,9,4), 
             finish = c(3,7,8,9,10,10,4,10,10,8))
dt %>% mutate(mean = (finish + start)/2)
```